# Octave fminunc doesn't converge

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I'm trying to use `fminunc` in Octave for a logistic problem, but it doesn't work. It says that I didn't define variables, but actually I did. If I define variables directly in the costFunction,and not in the main, it doesn't give any problem, but the function doesn't work really. In fact the `exitFlag` is equal to -3 and it doesn't converge at all.

Here's my function:

```
function [jVal, gradient] = cost(theta, X, y)

X = [1,0.14,0.09,0.58,0.39,0,0.55,0.23,0.64;1,-0.57,-0.54,-0.16,0.21,0,-0.11,-0.61,-0.35;1,0.42,0.45,-0.41,-0.6,0,-0.44,0.38,-0.29];
y = [1;0;1];
theta = [0.8;0.2;0.6;0.3;0.4;0.5;0.6;0.2;0.4];


jVal = 0;
jVal = costFunction2(X, y, theta);   %this is another function that gives me jVal. I'm quite sure it is 
                                     %correct because I use it also with other algorithms and it  
                                     %works perfectly
m = length(y);
xSize = size(X, 2);
gradient = zeros(xSize, 1);
sig = X * theta;
h = 1 ./(1 + exp(-sig));
  
  for i = 1:m
  
    for j = 1:xSize    
    gradient(j) =  (1/m) * sum(h(i) - y(i)) .* X(i, j);      
    end
    
   end
```

Here's my main:

```
theta = [0.8;0.2;0.6;0.3;0.4;0.5;0.6;0.2;0.4];
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 100);
[optTheta, functionVal, exitFlag] = fminunc(@cost, theta, options)
```

if I compile it:

```
optTheta =

   0.80000
   0.20000
   0.60000
   0.30000
   0.40000
   0.50000
   0.60000
   0.20000
   0.40000

functionVal =  0.15967
exitFlag = -3
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not in fact using `fminunc` correctly. From the documentation:

```
 -- fminunc (FCN, X0)
 -- fminunc (FCN, X0, OPTIONS)

     FCN should accept a vector (array) defining the unknown variables,
     and return the objective function value, optionally with gradient.
     'fminunc' attempts to determine a vector X such that 'FCN (X)' is a
     local minimum.
```

What you are passing is not a handle to a function that accepts a single vector argument. Instead, what you are passing (i.e. `@cost`) is a handle to a function that takes *three* arguments.

You need to 'convert' this into a handle to a function that takes only *one* input, and does what you want under the hood. The easiest way to do this is by 'wrapping' your cost function into an anonymous function that only takes one argument, and calls the `cost` function in the appropriate way, e.g.

```
fminunc( @(t) cost(t, X, y), theta, options )
```

---

<sub>Note: This assumes X and y are defined in the scope where you do this 'wrapping' business</sub>

Comment: I followed your advice. Now it converges, but also if functionVal ≈ 0, y ≈ [1;1;1] while it should be y ≈ [1;0;1]. In particular y = [0.96021;0.86053;0.99999]. What's the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if there are more problems, but your gradient formulation effectively discards all observations except the last one. (presumably it should have involved a sum over all observations instead; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_loss_function_and_logistic_regression )